# Facebook cup boomerang programming

Tags: python, algorithm

I was trying to solve one of the qualification problems in Facebook hackercup 2016, Boomerang constellations. (http://codeforces.com/gym/100869/attachments/download/4028/2016-facebook-hacker-cup-qualification-round-en.pdf)

My algorithm was for each star point, compute the distances to the other stars, and use a python dictionary to hash other points using the distance key.

Then I compute the possible boomerang constellations by computing n*(n-1)/2 for each list by distance.

When I ran the input and output provided by Facebook, the answers are correct. But When I submit this code to codeforces, it failed with "time limit exceed". Could you point out which part of the code is ineffective? Would this be the Python's problem?

```
import math
def findBoomerang(stars):
sum = 0
N = len(stars)
for i in range(N):
    lines = {}
    for j in range(N):
        if i == j:
            continue
        length = round(distance(stars[i], stars[j]), 3)
        if length not in lines:
            lines[length] = list()
        lines[length].append(stars[j])
    for i in lines.keys():
        n = len(lines[i])
        sum+=(int)(n*(n-1)/2)
return (int)(sum)

def distance(starA, starB):
(x1, y1) = starA
(x2, y2) = starB
return math.sqrt((x2-x1)*(x2-x1) + (y2-y1)*(y2-y1))


nights = int(input())
for night in range(nights):
    num_stars = int(input())
    stars = list()
    for i in range(num_stars):
        x,y = [int(x) for x in input().split(" ")]
        stars.append((x,y))
    constellations = findBoomerang(stars)
    print("Case #"+ str(night+1)+ ": "+ str(constellations))
```

Comment: Your code have a 3-level nested loop (one in the outer code, two in the findBoomerang), that are each bounded by the number of stars. The rules say there may be up to 2000 stars in a night. That means you have a worst case of 2000*2000*2000 iterations of the inner loop, which is probably why your algorithm exceeds the time limit.

Comment: Incidentally, the outer loop looks wrong - `constellations = findBoomerang(stars)` should probably be dedented?

Comment: @TomDalton Sorry, the outer loop was wrong. As you said, constellations = findBoomerang(stars) should be dedented (that's what I did in the code I submitted, just a copy-and-paste error here).

Comment: @TomDalton The time limit got caught in one of the test cases, and I think we need to exclude the outer loop because that's just for processing N inputs. The algorithm itself takes O(N^2).

Comment: one source of problem here is using double data type for length, doubles are exact to 1e-16 not more ,
I suggest you to read [this](https://www.topcoder.com/community/data-science/data-science-tutorials/representation-of-integers-and-reals-section-2/) 
short explaination : so the distance 1.10000000000000001 is same as 1.10000000000000002 in the question but, in built-in data structures of languages this point is omitted and may threat this values as different distances, in double data type you should always use a threshold for checking of equality.

Answer (score 1):

Two small improvements.

First, use length squared for your key rather then length.  That removes a *lot* of square root operations.

Second, there is no need to make a list of all stars of a given length away.  Instead you can just count them.

Comment: Additionally, while you avoid comparing a star with itself, you are still comparing both A with B and B with A, because of your `for i in range`, `for j in range` nest.